# Gradle ide log error and how to remove it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I replace the older version of gradle with the new one checked the auto detect proxy settings but the error remains the same now what should I do??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Qmf.png

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710214/how-to-solve-this-in-android-studio-3-0/48710607#48710607

Comment: no work for me..